# Can I use CASE in JOIN condition

Tags: sql, join, db2, case

I am getting error while using CASE in JOIN statement. Below is the query. I have masked the contents. Please let me know where I am going wrong. As it looks fine to me. Pasted the error aswell.

```
SELECT
    S1.NR AS "a",
    S1.ZTV AS "b",
    S1.RNR AS "c",
    S1.TW AS "d",
    S1.STV AS "e",
    S1.RTV "f",
    S1.DA AS "v",
    CASE 
        WHEN S1.ZTV = '115' THEN 'T_RR' 
        ELSE ' ' 
    END AS "DT",
    ' ' AS "SiT",
    S1.S1JL AS "Ns",
    S1.S1JM AS "Vs",
    S1.S1JN AS "NSv",
    S1.S1JO AS "VSf",
    S1.S1JP AS "Vse",
    S1.S1JQ AS "Vde",
    S1.S1JR AS "Vds" 
FROM
    XXXX S1 
JOIN
    YYYYY B 
        ON S1.S1R1TW = B.BUKSCD 
        AND  (
            CASE 
                WHEN B1.BUSX != ' ' 
                AND S1.S1TV = B1.BTX THEN 1 
                WHEN S1.S1TV = B1.B2TX THEN 1
                ELSE 0

            END
        )
```

I am getting the below error
Message: [SQL0104] Token  was not valid. Valid tokens: < > = <> <= !< !> != >= ¬< ¬> ¬= IN. Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token .  Token  is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is < > = <> <= !< !> != >= ¬< ¬> ¬= IN.  This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   Do one or more of the following and try the request again: -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of the token . Correct the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or quotation mark, it could be a misspelled word, or it could be related to the order of clauses. -- If the error token is , correct the SQL statement because it does not end with a valid clause.

Comment: This kind of problems may depend on technology used. Which db are you using? You may also think to move case block to to a function if functions supported.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid SQL:

```
       CASE WHEN B1.BUSX != ' ' AND S1.S1TV = B1.BTX THEN 1 
            WHEN S1.S1TV = B1.B2TX THEN 1
            ELSE 0
```

(although some databases do support it).  Instead, use `OR`:

```
( (B1.BUSX <> ' ' AND S1.S1TV = B1.BTX) OR
  (B1.BUSX = ' ')
)
```

I should point out that you *can* use `CASE`, but you need some comparison afterwards:

```
  (CASE WHEN B1.BUSX != ' ' AND S1.S1TV = B1.BTX THEN 1 
        WHEN S1.S1TV = B1.B2TX THEN 1
   ELSE 0) = 1
```

However, I think the basic boolean operations are simpler.